# I need help on INSERT statements using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I need to use an INSERT statement, and 2 of the records in this statement are fields which are calculated in the program, and need to be added to the database.

```
System.out.println("Executing....");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "INSERT INTO Identities"
              + " VALUES"
              + "('John', 'Smith', '38 Turpington Lane', 'Farnborough', 'Hampshire', 'HA6 7AF', '1990-03-01', PKmod, PKexpo)";
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

'PKmod' and 'PKexpo' are BigInteger fields whose value is calculated in the java program, how can I add these values to the database?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not insert sqls this way. Use [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Change your sql to use "?" markers instead of concatenating values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the DBMS. For mysql perhaps BIGINT should suffice?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to concatenate the string!!!!
So do as follows:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Identities"
              + " VALUES"
              + "('John', 'Smith', '38 Turpington Lane', 'Farnborough', 'Hampshire', 'HA6 7AF', '1990-03-01',"+ PKmod+", "+PKexpo+")";
```

Comment: @CoolBeans: He's not asking what's the best practice in regards to executing sql statements on mysql; he's asking what's wrong with his statement. Using PreparedStatements is not the best solution either. MySQL supports stored procedures for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println("Executing....");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql;
sql = "INSERT INTO Identities"
    + " VALUES"
    + "('John', 'Smith', '38 Turpington Lane', 'Farnborough', 'Hampshire', 'HA6 7AF', '1990-03-01', "
    + PKmod 
    + ", "
    + PKexpo
    + ")";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

// First Check That PKmod & PKexpo values are not Zero Or Null.

System.out.println("Executing....");

```
      String sql = "INSERT INTO Identities"
          + " VALUES"
          + "('John', 'Smith', '38 Turpington Lane', 'Farnborough', 'Hampshire', 'HA6 7AF', '1990-03-01'," + PKmod + "," + PKexpo +")";

    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    pStmt.executeUpdate();
    closePreparedStatement(pStmt);
```

Comment: Where is a problem in my cod ... ??